# CNContactViewControllerをPeekしようとすると真っ白い画面になることがある

Tags: ios

名前を強く押された(Peek)ら連絡先情報を表示しようとしています。

UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegateの
previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation:で
[CNContactViewController viewControllerForContact:contact];を使ってCNContactViewControllerのインスタンスを取得しています。

しかし、テストすると表示される人と表示されない人があり表示されない場合は

plugin com.apple.MobileAddressBook.ContactViewViewService interrupted
viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

というログが書き出されています。
表示される・されない人は常に同じなので、連絡先データが関連しているようにも思えます。

何をチェックすればいいのでしょうか？

ちなみに実機(iOS 9.0.2, iOS 9.1)でテストしています。

Comment: 試行錯誤していてメールアドレスにAppleID?iCloud?のメールアドレスを指定している場合、「発信 FaceTime オーディオ」が有効になり、その連絡先の場合上記エラーが発生して何も表示されないようです。
何か設定が必要なのかな？

Answer (score 2):

その後のテストでUINavigationControllerに含まれていると問題ないことがわかりました。しかし、それだと問題があるのでその方法は使えません。

解決策としてCNContactViewControllerのdisplayedPropertyKeysに任意の項目だけを指定することで回避することができました。